# Adding a custom installation directory option to Autoconf-generated configure scripts

Tags: installation, autoconf, configure, automake, make-install

`configure` scripts always include something like the following in the help message:

```
...
By default, `make install' will install all the files in
`/usr/local/bin', `/usr/local/lib' etc.  You can specify
an installation prefix other than `/usr/local' using `--prefix',
for instance `--prefix=$HOME'.

For better control, use the options below.

Fine tuning of the installation directories:
  --bindir=DIR            user executables [EPREFIX/bin]
  --sbindir=DIR           system admin executables [EPREFIX/sbin]
  --libexecdir=DIR        program executables [EPREFIX/libexec]
  --sysconfdir=DIR        read-only single-machine data [PREFIX/etc]
  --sharedstatedir=DIR    modifiable architecture-independent data [PREFIX/com]
  --localstatedir=DIR     modifiable single-machine data [PREFIX/var]
  --libdir=DIR            object code libraries [EPREFIX/lib]
  --includedir=DIR        C header files [PREFIX/include]
  --oldincludedir=DIR     C header files for non-gcc [/usr/include]
  --datarootdir=DIR       read-only arch.-independent data root [PREFIX/share]
  --datadir=DIR           read-only architecture-independent data [DATAROOTDIR]
  --infodir=DIR           info documentation [DATAROOTDIR/info]
  --localedir=DIR         locale-dependent data [DATAROOTDIR/locale]
  --mandir=DIR            man documentation [DATAROOTDIR/man]
  --docdir=DIR            documentation root
                          [DATAROOTDIR/doc/gedit-line-ending-style-plugin]
  --htmldir=DIR           html documentation [DOCDIR]
  --dvidir=DIR            dvi documentation [DOCDIR]
  --pdfdir=DIR            pdf documentation [DOCDIR]
  --psdir=DIR             ps documentation [DOCDIR]

Program names:
  --program-prefix=PREFIX            prepend PREFIX to installed program names
...
```

What I would like to do is add "plugindir", to this section, as in:

```
...
  --dvidir=DIR            dvi documentation [DOCDIR]
  --pdfdir=DIR            pdf documentation [DOCDIR]
  --psdir=DIR             ps documentation [DOCDIR]
  --plugindir=DIR         Gedit plugin files [LIBDIR/gedit-2/plugins]
...
```

so that users would be able to pass in `--plugindir=...` to the configure script.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make install, but not to default directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239343/make-install-but-not-to-default-directories)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm correct those paths are set in the share/autoconf/autoconf/general.m4 file. The list is hardcoded so it is difficult to insert things in the list. You can add extra help information using the macro [`AS_HELP_STRING`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Pretty-Help-Strings). 
There are some examples that add a plugindir, for example in [gstreamer](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/common/tree/m4/gst-plugindir.m4), [gimp](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gimp/tree/configure.ac?h=GIMP_2_9_2#n2077), but those don't have a configurable plugin directory.

Comment: Interesting. Line 1058 of my `/usr/share/autoconf/autoconf/general.m4` file is responsible for the "Fine tuning of the installation directories:" line. It does not, however, appear that I can easily add to the "installation directories" section of the `configure` script help text without modifying `general.m4`. But, at least I now know.

Comment: I am not sure which approach of gstreamer and xine you are referring to. But, what I did was adapted a line from `general.m4`, adding `AC_SUBST([plugindir], ['${libdir}/gedit-2/plugins'])` to my `configure.ac`. Then, I specify targets that I want to install to the "plugindir" in the `plugin_DATA` variable in a `Makefile.am`. It's not as user-configurable as I was originally going for, but it works well: http://code.google.com/p/gedit-line-ending-style-plugin/source/browse/trunk/src/Makefile.am

Comment: Neither gstreamer nor xine do what the OP was asking. Both set the plugin path without any way for the user to specify. The only way I can see to allow the user to specify a plugin path at configure time is to abuse AC_ARG_WITH, which puts the documentation under "optional packages" rather than "fine tuning of the installation directories."

Comment: general.m4 is an internal file of autoconf, don't mess with it. The link is dead. But from what I see, everybody uses `AC_ARG_WITH`. Adding an argument without "with" or "enable" is impossible without modifying Autoconf.

Answer (score 4):

Put the following lines in `configure.ac`, near the beginning:

```
AC_ARG_WITH([pkgconfigdir],
  [AS_HELP_STRING([--with-pkgconfigdir=DIR], [pkgconfig files])],
  [pkgconfigdir=$withval],
  [pkgconfigdir="\${libdir}/pkgconfig"])
AC_SUBST([pkgconfigdir], [$pkgconfigdir])
```

Then, in `Makefile.am`, you can refer to the directory like this:

```
pkgconfigdir = @pkgconfigdir@
pkgconfig_DATA = mylibrary.pc
```

Comment: The second argument is not needed. `pkgconfigdir = @pkgconfigdir@` is not needed. It's nice to specify the default in the help. You can use single quotes instead of escaping `$`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track with AC_SUBST.

Additionally, I think you can modify or extend the --help output of configure with AS_HELP_STRING.

See: http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/autoconf/Pretty-Help-Strings.html