# how to modify the install-path without running the configure script/cmake again

Tags: makefile, cmake, configure, build-system

I am working on a project which takes considerable time to build (10-15) minutes. I have recompiled to verify if there is a compilation error. Now I want to change the install directory so that I have a new version of executable with the new changes. Is there a method to just modify the install path so that the 'make install' installs to a new location rather than the old one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make install - but not to default directories?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239343/make-install-but-not-to-default-directories)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

CMake generated makefiles support the [DESTDIR coding convention](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/DESTDIR.html) for makefiles. Thus you can override the default installation location by setting the `DESTDIR` variable upon invoking make:

```
$ make install DESTDIR=/opt/local
```

There is no need to re-run CMake.

Comment: I just came across this and I don't think that should be the accepted answer. Best should be to re-run cmake with `cmake . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<some_install_path>` which does **not** recompile your project. With using `DESTDIR` files still get prepared with only the default prefix (see generated `install_manifest.txt`). This is particularly bad if you want to uninstall etc.

Comment: This answer has been posted on 21.1.2012, Monday... I tried this on 28.6.2020, Tuesday... I copied this command and modified the folder name... and I pasted it in the terminal.. pressed enter.. and then The beauty is that this still works during 2020... thank you @sakra

Answer (score 27):

I don't know whether this is generally true, but I can give an example of an application for which [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13488348/1168152) by `sakra` does not work properly. If you modify the install directory by modifying `DESTDIR` when installing ITK, it will just append `DESTDIR` to its already formed install path:

```
make install DESTDIR=/opt/local
```

[...]

```
-- Installing: /opt/local/usr/local/lib/cmake/ITK-4.4/WrapITK/Configuration/Typedefs/itkRenyiEntropy[...]
```

On the other hand, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13485019/1168152) by `Fraser` will result in proper install paths without recompilation:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/local /path/to/ITK_source
make install
```

[...]

```
-- Installing: /opt/local/lib/cmake/ITK-4.4/WrapITK/Configuration/Typedefs/itkRenyiEntropy[...]
```

Answer (score 22):

Running CMake with `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<somewhere different to last time>` shouldn't cause your project to need recompiled.  If you pass other command line parameters to CMake which e.g. alter the compiler flags, that *would* force a rebuild of affected targets, but simply changing the install prefix won't.

Comment: Is there a way to change the install prefix without rerunning cmake? It seems that CPACK is capable of doing so, but I cannot see a way for me to do it directly just using make + some variable. If I want to create a package with my own packager, I want to get things under /usr rather than /usr/local, but I'd like that to work without having to ask the programmer to run cmake with the correct CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX...

Comment: Well, you could use `set` in your CMakeLists.txt to hard-code the value of `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`, but I think this is fairly uncommon and might catch out people who are already used to CMake.  Maybe a better option would be to print out a `message` in your CMakeLists.txt which displays the current value of `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` and also gives instructions as to how to change the value.  Something like `message("The install path is currently ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}")` `message("To change this run:  cmake . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=\"<new install path>\"")`

Answer (score 11):

The canonical definition of DESTDIR and prefix is: the files are installed to $DESTDIR$prefix, but prepared as if their final install location was just $prefix.

So DESTDIR is only for people building packages or tarballs of binaries;
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX is for anyone who wants to specify where the built binaries should live in the end.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case if someone is not using CMake then there is a method to do that in Makefile. If you have Makefile.config file generated in your build directory, find the `prefix`. This `prefix` is the install `path` where binaries/headers etc. will be installed. Changing this will install the binaries/headers to the modified `path`.