# changing the path of make install

Tags: makefile, cmake

I am installing a library using its own CMakeLists.txt file and I accidently set the option CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX to a different directory than what I had intended.  I already ran `make` and I know running `make install` will cause the library files to be installed in the wrong directory.  To solve this problem I can simply rerun `cmake` with the correct CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX, run `make` and then run `make install` but that requires the library to be rebuilt again which takes some time.  Is there a quick way to fix this where I can simply change the target directory of `make install`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480846/how-to-modify-the-install-path-without-running-the-configure-script-cmake-again

Comment: thank you, although the _DDESDIR didn't work for me (library was still installed in the wrong dir) re-running cmake without running make again worked for me.