# 'make install' into a conda environment

Tags: installation, makefile, conda

While in a conda environment (`source activate`), how can I `make install` into the environment library directories (`lib`, `bin`, etc.) and not the system directories?

Note that I do NOT want answers related to `conda-build`.

Comment: With the environment activated, the environment variable `$CONDA_PREFIX` points to the prefix of the environment, e.g., `/home/user/miniconda3/envs/env-name`. From there you can add `lib`, `bin`, etc.

Comment: @xaav Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: You would find the root path to your conda environment (maybe, `$CONDA_PREFIX` from above), then provide it to the `configure` command as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3239373/1509695) if you're lucky to have the make definition having been originally created in a very standard way by the authors of the project which builds the package you are installing, as mentioned on this link just included.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-C` (change directory) argument to tell `make` to use a different directory:

```sh
make -C $CONDA_PREFIX/lib install
```

From the manual:

```
 -C dir, --directory=dir
            Change  to directory dir before reading the makefiles or doing anything else.
```